# Listview flickering on notifyDataSetChanged() when using universal image loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am facing the same issue which is mentioned in the link given below:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/376

I have checked the solutions in the above link and it seems like the given below solution is solving the problem:

```
ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(imageView, false);
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageAware);
```

But the same flickering issue will happen, if I pass the options to `displayImage`() method in the above code. That means, the below code is causing issue:

```
ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(imageView, false);
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageAware,options);
```

How can I stop the flickering issue when when I am passing 'options' to the `displayImage()` method?

Here is the option which I am passing to the method:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable,loading).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.failed).cacheOnDisc(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).build();
```

Comment: :i also face the same issue .want sol'n of it. if you got any solution then please shear with us .

Comment: @Jigs: I replaced that library with Picasso and it has no such issues.  Here is the link: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: can i use that picasso libs with unioversal image loader ??or i have to modify my code as per the link suggest ??

Comment: @Jigs: It will be better if you modify it. I have completely removed universal image loader and now using only Picasso.

Comment: i completely replaced universal loader with picasso but still i'm getting flickering issue in downloading images .when i'm trying to store images in to cache,it working fine but i did't get new uploaded images coming from server ,and if im clear that cache then flickering happen .any sol'n for that ????

Comment: @Jigs: Why you are trying to add images to cache? Picasso can handle the caching itself. You need not have to cache anything manually. You only have to call this Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView); in you custom adapter.

Comment: you are right brother but i m not getting newly uploaded images from server if im not clear cache.for that i used cache.clear of PicassoTools class.is there any problem in my code @roy mathew

Comment: @Jigs: It is better to upload each image with a unique name, so that the URLs will be different for different images. So every new/ updated image will be different from previous image. Issue is that, you are using same name for image, even if it is replaced, so Picasso will think that the image is already loaded and no need to load again.

Comment: the images are stored as different name like "username@imagename". i m working on simple chat application.my problem is that while i m returning from chat activity to friendlist activity ,the profile images of friends which may be change during my chat conversation ,is not updated in listview (friendlist activity).is it listview problem ?? i also try notifyDatasetchanged method for that @roy mathew

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not reload your image when it did not change.

In your adapters getView() do:

```
// schedule rendering:
final String path = ... (set path here);
if (holder.lastImageUrl == null || !holder.lastImageUrl.equals(path)
                || holder.headerImageView.getDrawable() == null) {
    // refresh image
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageAware);
} else {
    // do nothing, image did not change and does not need to be updated
}
```

on success (add a ImageLoadingListener) you set holder.lastImageUrl = path, on fail and cancel you set holder.lastImageUrl to null so that it will reload next time.